# how to execute only specific changesets in liquibase which are unread?

Tags: liquibase

I have added some new changesets in an existing changelog file and want to execute only 2 among the new inserted ones. When I give the update command in liquibase it updates all the unread changesets and updates the database. But I want to execute only 2 among these newly inserted changesets in the changelog file. Is there any way of doing this in liquibase? If yes how is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do this is to mark the relevant changesets with a label, and then use that label in your `liquibase update` command.

This [blog post on labels](http://www.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html) describes their use.

Here is an example that matches what you described in your comment below.

**changelog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<databaseChangeLog 
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="steve" labels="labelOne">
        <createTable tableName="tableOne">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="2" author="steve" labels="labelTwo">
        <comment>Creating table "tableTwo"</comment>
        <createTable tableName="tableTwo">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="3" author="steve" labels="labelThree">
        <comment>Creating table "tableThree"</comment>
        <createTable tableName="tableThree">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**command execution**

If you wanted to update and only create table one, you would use this command (if you are using the command line, and assuming that you have a liquibase.properties file that specifies all the connection information, etc.)

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --labels=labelOne update
```

If you wanted to apply two changesets, you would use a command like this:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --labels="labelOne and labelTwo" update
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to label them with contexts but unfortunately the update command is executing the other changesets also\

Comment: can you just explain how to use the labels ?

Comment: I might if you give me a full example of what you want to do.

Comment: I have added three changesets suppose to an existing changelog file. changeset 1,changeset 2, changeset 3. I want to execute only changeset 1 among this. While defining the changesets I am writing <changeset author-"" id="" label="">. But the problem is that while updateing its giving there is no attribute as label. Son can you just explain the exact syntax please?

Comment: It looks like the Liquibase documentation is missing some details and examples on labels. Example added above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its working now just the way I wanted it t work. I have one more question though. How to use the rollback tag?

Comment: If you have another question, please:
1. search with google
2. if you can't figure it out, submit another question to StackOverflow describing what you have tried, what you expect to happen, what actually happened.

See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask